# How to calculate average difference between the values for each object?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table orders which have next structure:

```
| Field       | Type         |
|-------------|--------------|
| id          | bigint(20)   |
| customer_id | int(11)      |
| item        | varchar(256) |
| price       | int(11)      |
```

I need to get the average value of the differences between the order's price per customer.
Let's say that customer with id 20 has the next orders

```
| id  | customer_id | item     | price |
|-----|-------------|----------|-------|
| 356 | 20          | Jacket   | 85    |
| 412 | 20          | Trousers | 32    |
| 781 | 20          | Gloves   | 15    |
| 802 | 20          | Boots    | 26    |
```

Differences between the order's price are next:

- [85-32] = 23
- [32-15] = 17
- [15-26] = 11

The average difference would be then (23 + 17 + 11) / 3 = 17

But it's required to calculate this average difference for all customers and find average value between them after

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Server version: 5.7.27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you would really want to use here is `LEAD()`, but your version of MySQL does not support that.  As a workaround, we can try using correlated subqueries to find the lead prices, then aggregate over that result to find the overall average:

```
SELECT
    SUM(price_diff) / ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders) - 1) AS avg_diff
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ABS(o1.price - COALESCE((SELECT o2.price FROM orders o2
                                 WHERE o2.id > o1.id
                                 ORDER BY o2.id LIMIT 1), o1.price)) price_diff
    FROM orders o1
) t;
```

Comment: Thank you! Will try it out! I think my version of MySQL should be one of the latest ones, so maybe LEAD is supported

Comment: That contradicts your `5.7.27` server version, which you cited above.

Comment: ah sorry my fault, yup, you are right, 5.7 was released October 21, 2015 referring to the Wikipedia page - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL